daterangepicker disable date
i have this script to user can reserve date but i want to disable the reserved date but he don t work can you help me ?
let days = []; // Initialize days array
$(document).ready(function() { // Retrieve the reserved dates passed from the server-side const reservedDates = @json($reservedDates).map(date => formatDate(new Date(date)));
Copy
// Log the reserved dates array to the console
console.log("Reserved Dates:", reservedDates);
$('#dateRnage').dateRangePicker({
singleMonth: true,
showShortcuts: false,
showTopbar: false,
startDate: new Date(), // Start date is today
isInvalidDate: function(date) {
// Format the date to 'YYYY-MM-DD'
const formattedDate = formatDate(date);
      // Log the date being checked to the console
      console.log("Checking Date:", formattedDate);

      // Disable the date if it matches any reserved date
      const isDisabled = reservedDates.includes(formattedDate);
      console.log(`Date ${formattedDate} is ${isDisabled ? 'disabled' : 'enabled'}`);
      return isDisabled;
  },

});
i want to disable same date but he don t work

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
